# How to catch RuntimeException thrown within a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Android `Fragment` embedded in my app. During deployment I have had certain Android subsystems throw undocumented `RuntimeException` instances. Annoying, but I figured I would just catch them in the `Activity` housing the `Fragment`. Unfortunately, I haven't been too successful at this so far.

My layout XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:name="com.my.ui.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/my_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To simulate a `RuntimeException`, I added this to `MyFragment.onResume`:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    throw new RuntimeException("Boom.");
}
```

To try to catch it in the Activity, I thought maybe it happens during the layout inflation process so I surrounded the `setContentView` call in a try-catch:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.base_layout);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
After I wrote this question, thought to try catching something from super.onResume() in `MyActivity.onResume` like this:

```
public void onResume() {
        try {
            super.onResume();
            ...
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "I caught something baby!!!");
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, no dice... it appears the Android framework maybe getting to it before my Activity can. Below is the relevant LogCat:

```
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033): Process: com.my.myactivity, PID: 29033
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.my.myactivity/com.my.myactivity.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Boom.
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Boom.
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at com.my.ui.MyFragment.onResume(MyFragment.java:97)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1863)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5320)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
02-06 16:19:36.908: E/AndroidRuntime(29033):    ... 12 more
```

Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown by a fragment during one of its lifecycle phases, or do I need to catch it and send the exception via `Handler` or custom callback interface?

Comment: you expect RuntimeExceptions? is there a reason you can't fix the root of the problem? Either way posting a stacktrace would help, besides maybe knowing the root cause it will reveal how the stack is called

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, Android throws RuntimeExceptions, especially when dealing with hardware. The fragment uses a `Camera` underneath, which will throw RuntimeExceptions occasionally since some manufacturers can't seem to develop solid drivers... But, everyone has bugs even the big dogs, I suppose :)

Comment: But, I would just like to know how to catch any Exception thrown from within a Fragment. RuntimeException just happens to be my current poison. The goal being a clean shutdown of the app instead of a crash.

Comment: @Jim Updated with the LogCat for ya.

Comment: Try putting code from onResume into a background thread - since you are talking about non-UI errors you should be able to encapsulate the problem in a separate thread when you can gracefully handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is calling onResume can catch this exception.
You cannot just catch it in another unrelated method like this.

Think what happens on the call stack.

Only if the call to onCreate causes the call to onResume
(directly or indirectly), then you can catch it in onCreate
provided no one else caught it already.

So if you have this chain of calls:
`some code -> onCreate -> A -> B -> C -> ... -> D -> onResume`
and methods D, ... , C, B, A do not catch the exception,
then you can catch it in onCreate.

I am not familiar with Android so answering a bit in general.

I seriously doubt you have this chain of calls in Android.
I guess the framework is calling both methods independently.
I mean just looking at the method names, I guess it doesn't
make sense to have this call chain which I wrote above.